# How do I iterate over the form values in python cgi ? Newbie

Tags: python, cgi

Let say i have a form with multiple fields. And in my cgi i am using this all values.For Example

```
res1 = form.getvalue("opt_1")
res2 = form.getvalue("opt_2")
res3 = form.getvalue("opt_3") 
res4 = form.getvalue("opt_4")
res5 = form.getvalue("opt_5")
       ...
       ...
res100 = form.getvalue("opt_100")
```

In my cgi , I am using a for loop to get the values

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    res[i] = form.getvalue('opt_[i]')
    print res[i]
```

I am getting an error: NameError: global name 'res' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't defined `res`, define it first:

```
res = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    res.append(form.getvalue('opt_%d'%i))
    print res[i-1]
```

Where res will be a list containing the results of `form.getvalue('opt_i')`s.

Comment: `res[i] = form.getvalue()` won't work when res doesn't have an index `i` yet. You need to do `res.append` to grow the list, and then each item will actually be at `res[i-1]`.

Comment: @lvc sorry, i missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems with your loop: first, `res` doesn't exist yet, so trying to assign to its items won't work. Second, if you create it as an empty list first, you can't expand it by writing past the end.

Fix both at once by using a list comprehension instead:

```
res = [form.getfirst('opt_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 100)]
```

This puts the value of `opt_1` at `res[0]`, and so on - if that is a problem, you could add a dummy element to the start of it:

```
res = [None] + [form.getfirst('opt_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 100)]
```

or use a dictionary instead:

```
res = {i: form.getfirst('opt_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 100)}
```

Note that, per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#higher-level-interface), you should avoid using `getvalue`, since it might return *either* a string *or* a list depending on user input. Use `form.getfirst` to instead guarantee that you will have a string.